# How can I automate connecting to wifi if the Access Point name changes occasionally?

Tags: networking, wifi-hotspot

I am a relative noob running linux mint 21.1 on a compute-stick type device. I want to be able to take this compute stick around my workplace, which spans multiple buildings. Currently, the buildings have unique names for each access point in the building. (ie "Access_1,"Access_2"...). The passwords for each are the same, but with a small change ("Password1", Password2",...) Since there are a lot of buildings, I was wondering if it would be possible to automate the detection and connection of these hotspots. Since I only turn on the compute stick when I'm close to the building, a startup script would be fine instead of continuous scanning.

How would I go about scripting this? Where would I even start?

Comment: Doesn't this work out of the box? The system will connect to whichever access point it can detect from among the ones it knows about. So as long as you have connected to the access point once, so the system knows about it, next time you are near it, it will connect to it as soon as the system is turned on. Isn't that what happens?

Comment: I should've clarified in the post- there are 100+ access points, and there are buildings I haven't been to and haven't connected to. It would be a pain to have to log in every single time when the passwords are so similar.

Comment: This really sounds like a lot more work than just connecting to the right one _once_ and having it be remembered next time. Do you at least have a list of all access point names and a corresponding list of their passwords?

Comment: I guess I could create one- all the networks are named some variation of "Access_#" and have a password of "Password_#" where the # is the number of the building.